# Json "for" loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to put information about video in #t1, #t2 and #t3, but everything is placed in #t3. Where is the mistake in the code?

```js
  $(function(){
        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            var box = "#t" + i;
            var id = "dQw4w9WgXcQ";
          
            var img = "<img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + id + "/default.jpg'>";
            console.log(i);

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + id +  '&key=AIzaSyBlYMwv6QQ9x3r1ACVt1ZeyiRXiaGeKOBU', function(data) {

                $(box).prepend("viewCount: " + data.items[ 0 ].statistics.viewCount);


            });
            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=' + id + '&key=AIzaSyBlYMwv6QQ9x3r1ACVt1ZeyiRXiaGeKOBU', function(data) {
                $(box).prepend("<h3>" + "Title" + data.items[0].snippet.title + "</h3>");
                $(box).prepend("<h3>" + "Channel title" + data.items[0].snippet.channelTitle + "</h3>");
                $(box).prepend(img);
            });
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t1"></div>
<div id="t2"></div>
<div id="t3"></div>
```

Comment: Look up how closures work in JavaScript! Your calls to $.getJSON() work asynchronously, the value for `box` is `#t3` by the time the callback is executed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, handler will be invoked when response is received. But `for-loop` will not wait for handler to be called!

Create a `inner-function` and pass value of `i` as argument as value of `i` will be persistent for the `inner-function`.

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var tobeCalled = function(i) {
      var box = "#t" + i;
      var id = "dQw4w9WgXcQ";
      var img = "<img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + id + "/default.jpg'>";
      $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + id + '&key=AIzaSyBlYMwv6QQ9x3r1ACVt1ZeyiRXiaGeKOBU', function(data) {
        $(box).prepend("viewCount: " + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
      });
      $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=' + id + '&key=AIzaSyBlYMwv6QQ9x3r1ACVt1ZeyiRXiaGeKOBU', function(data) {
        $(box).prepend("<h3>" + "Title" + data.items[0].snippet.title + "</h3>");
        $(box).prepend("<h3>" + "Channel title" + data.items[0].snippet.channelTitle + "</h3>");
        $(box).prepend(img);
      });
    }
    tobeCalled(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t1">
  <h2>1</h2>
</div>
<div id="t2">
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>
<div id="t3">
  <h2>3</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 3):

`Closures...`  wrap everything in a closure which would create a new `scope` for each iteration.

```
$(function(){      
        for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
          (function(i)
            var box = "#t" + i;
            var id = "dQw4w9WgXcQ";

            var img = "<img src='https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + id + "/default.jpg'>";
            console.log(i);

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + id +  '&key=AIzaSyBlYMwv6QQ9x3r1ACVt1ZeyiRXiaGeKOBU', function(data) {

                $(box).prepend("viewCount: " + data.items[ 0 ].statistics.viewCount);


            });
            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=' + id + '&key=AIzaSyBlYMwv6QQ9x3r1ACVt1ZeyiRXiaGeKOBU', function(data) {
                $(box).prepend("<h3>" + "Title" + data.items[0].snippet.title + "</h3>");
                $(box).prepend("<h3>" + "Channel title" + data.items[0].snippet.channelTitle + "</h3>");
                $(box).prepend(img);
            });
        }
       })(i);
    });
```